# Why my code is not working for problem (Marathon) Code forces

Tags: c++, c++17

You are given four distinct integers a, b, c, d.

Timur and three other people are running a marathon. The value a is the distance that Timur has run and b, c, d correspond to the distances the other three participants ran.

Output the number of participants in front of Timur.

Input
The first line contains a single integer t (1≤t≤104) — the number of test cases.

The description of each test case consists of four distinct integers a, b, c, d (0≤a,b,c,d≤104).

Output
For each test case, output a single integer — the number of participants in front of Timur.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, p(0);
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int a, b, c, d, x;
        cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
        if (b > a) {
            p++;
        } else if (c > a) {
            p++;
        } else if (d > a) {
            p++;
        }
        cout << p << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug it?

Comment: Remove both `else` and it looks good to me. Remember what else means, if `b > a` is true then `c > a` and `d > a` won't even be considered.

Comment: Are you using codeforces to learn C++? If so be aware the code/solutions there do not really follow good C++ coding practices. For that get a book or have a look at https://www.learncpp.com/

Comment: Note also `p` should be initialized for each iteration of testcase.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I've took a pick on this source and I didn't like what I've seen there, example: `Best practice

Consider using a “g” or “g_” prefix for global variables to help differentiate them from local variables.` - best practice is NOT to use global variables at all.

Comment: @MarekR Yes I found out it kept adding the values to the next test case so I tried putting a return 0; and it still kept adding on how would u initialize a variable if return 0; doesn't work.

Comment: @MarekR Well the prefix that's style and is always debatable  and yes global variables are bad :). But in general the site does a whole lot better then the competitive sites and is pretty up-to-date. And regrettably the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) only make sense if you already know a bit of C++.

Comment: @hazey `return 0;` returns a value of zero from a function. It's got nothing to do with initialising variables. Honestly you will learn basic C++ concepts far more **quickly** from a book, than by trying out puzzles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `else if`s to `if`s and declaring the variable `p` inside the loop:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(0);
  int t;
  cin >> t;
  while (t--) {
    int p = 0;
    int a, b, c, d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    if (b > a) {
      p++;
    }
    if (c > a) {
      p++;
    }
    if (d > a) {
      p++;
    }
    cout << p << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
4
2 3 4 1
10000 0 1 2
500 600 400 300
0 9999 10000 9998
2
0
1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

When using "else if" you only check the "else if" if the if wasn't true, so in this case
if b > a is true then the others won't be checked, to check individually you should just use if each time instead of else if